# Library to create reduction coderef using defined rules

Tags: perl, object, reduce

Is there an existing CPAN library that's able to create coderefs from a structured input of basic tests that reduce a passed data structure to a true/false value? it needs to be able to map passed attributes from the constructor onto the passed data structure's attributes (i.e., in the example below `[attribute => 'something']` maps to `$_->{something}` on the passed scalar) and perform tests against them.

I could write something, but I'm really surprised I'm not finding anything on CPAN to handle it. Does anyone know of a library to do this sort of thing?

```
my @def = ( [ [ attribute => 'something' ], '>', 50 ],
            'and',
            [ [ attribute => 'something_else' ], 'eq', 'match' ],
          );

my $coderef = Reducer->new(@def);

my @items = ( { something => 75,
                something_else => 'match',
              },
              { something => 20,
                something_else => 'match',
              },
              { something => 75,
                something_else => 'no match',
              },
              { something => 90,
                something_else => 'match',
              },
            );

for my $item (@items) {
  $coderef->($item) ? say 'true' : say 'false';
};
```

outputs:

```
true
false
false
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing about this problem or indeed your example code cries out to be solved by a coderef to me; you are more likely to find a subroutine that takes both the definition and item to validate as parameters.

I know there are several of those; the one that comes to mind first is [Params::Validate::validate](http://p3rl.org/Params%3a%3aValidate#SYNOPSIS).

It would be trivial to wrap your desired interface around that, though the definition structure would differ from yours (a hash of attribute to validation spec instead of an array, etc).

```
package Params::Validate::Reducer;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Params::Validate ();
sub new {
    my ($class, $def) = @_;
    sub {
        !! eval {
            Params::Validate::validate(@_, $def);
            1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only reason I was leaning towards a compiled coderef is that there are going to be relatively few rules with many checks run against them over the life of the program, and I was hoping to not to have to interpret the rule reference every time something it checked. May be premature optimization, though, and I don't mind ditching that idea. What are the other validation modules you reccommend, just for comparisons' sake?

Comment: I know I've seen several others (often distributed with the unrelated code that uses them) but I can't recall which.  Params::Validate is certainly no speed demon, and its "global options" interface is IMO really poorly designed, so you may be best off creating the kind of compiled coderef you envisioned yourself.

Comment: Yeah, after skimming through the Params::Validate POD I'm leaning towards that myself. What this is really meant to handle is just to be able to define from config to look at an arbitrary arrayref with things like `if (scalar @{$_} > 10)` and `if ((uniq map {$_->{foo}} @$_) < 3)` and the like, and when evaluating true to run a callback. Simple enough, I'm just surprised I'm not finding something to plug in to do it.

Comment: It's the kind of thing where there are endless variations in the details of what people may want, which leads to everybody doing their own, I think.